# Can't connect to wifi with Intel 7265AC on Ubuntu 16.04 LST

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, intel

Frist, I am sory for my english.

I have a problem with wifi on ubuntu 16.04.

My laptop is ASUS model K501UB use Intel Wireless 7265AC card. But it not working on Ubuntu 16.04.

I got these firmware-files from https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware and copied to /lib/firmware. But it not working.

```
$ ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7265
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180224 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180412 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Th10  7 20:15 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384256 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384060 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1383604 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1375112 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1387836 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1388680 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1385368 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1028316 Th02  7 14:31 iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
```

I try rf-kill.

```
$ rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Please help me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the switch or key combination set to enable wireless? Is the key combination not working as expected?

Is the module asus_nb_wmi loaded? Check:

```
lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, please try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
exit
```

Reboot and see if the Fn+F2 behavior is changed.

If the above does not work, redo it again but replace asus_nb_wmi wapf=0 with asus_nb_wmi wapf=1, and if that does not work, replace it with asus_nb_wmi wapf=4 instead.

Comment: `wapf=4` is the most common according to the kernel quirks.